# Why does Javascript keep removing forward slashes from a URL concatenated with a string in setting up this Google Analytics event tracker?

Tags: javascript

If I have a piece of Javascript where *$(some_block.url).attr("href")* is equivalent to *http://example.org/events/204*:

```
var text = '<div class="title"><a href="' + $(some_block.url).attr("href") + '" onclick=ga(\'send\',\'event\',\'Event Label Dude\',\'' + $(some_block.url).attr("href") + '\')' + ' target="_blank">' + some_block.title + '</a></div>';
```

When interpolated I wind up with something like:

```
<a href="http://example.org/events/204" onclick="ga('send','event','Event" label="" dude','http:="" example.org="" events="" 204')="" target="_blank">Some Event</a>
```

What is going on?  Are the forward slashes in the URL being removed because I try to enclose them in single quotes?  I'm trying to add a URL in a code snippet for google analytics event tracking.

Comment: It's likely just some sanitization happening pre submission. Have you tried escaping them? Or using character encodings?

Comment: The onclick attribute isn't wrapped in quotes so it splits it up as if it's multiple different attributes.

Comment: Double quote issue? This is your onclick as far as the parser is concerned `onclick="ga('send','event','Event"`

Comment: thanks, I had to wrap the "ga" in double quotes.